# OpenGL 3.2 on El Capitan

Tags: opengl, glut

I have shaders written in GLSL version 150, so I believe I need to get an OpenGL 3.2 context.

If I do:

```
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE | ...)
```

then the OpenGL version is 4.1, if I don't then the version is 2.1.

If the version is 4.1, then `GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader` is false which the code checks for before it starts.

Answer (score 2):

The `ARB_vertex_shader` is [an extension of the **compatibility** profile](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_shader.txt) that allows you to use a vertex shader with old versions of OpenGL. You don't need this extension with the **core** profile. I think your code can run safely without this check.

OpenGL 4.1 should allow you to do anything you would do with OpenGL3.2.

Chances are, the code you use was not written in a OSX environment. Other OS allows to activate both **Core** and **Compatibility** profile at the same time. This is [not the case with OSX](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts). This suggest that your code depends on this feature so it might be tricky to get it to work on OSX.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't written on OS X, there are a bunch of includes within a `#if __APPLE__` however implying at one time it worked on OSX. If I remove the check then it crashes at runtime with a generic error code

Comment: Hum, I think some code might try to explicitly use compatibility features. I don't think I can help you solve it if that's the case. Sorry.

Comment: @Jonathan: It probably crashes, because the code tries to use GLEW, which is pretty much useless on MacOS X. And with GLEW headers being included but GLEW not initializes you'll hit uninitialized function pointers. Find all occurrances of the string "glew" in your code (case insensitive) and where ever it creeps up, surround its use with a `#ifndef __APPLE__` … `#endif/*__APPLE__*/` bracket.